# Replace a string at a fixed position in a text file with the output of a command with cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

I wants to replace the `QUICKSERVER` string in line 3 of my text file which is located at `c:\BR.txt` with the output from the `hostname` command in Windows CMD. `hostname` is a Windows command which returns the system name.

```
C:\>hostname
QUICKSERVER
```

my text file is:

```
  userName=Administrator
  password=
  CMS=QUICKSERVER:6400
  authentication=secEnterprise
```

Please find the command which I can execute in the Windows command line to replace the hostname with `QUICKSERVER`.

Answer (score 0):

The host name can also be found in the `%computername%` environment variable, so you don't need the `hostname` command.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%L in (c:\br.txt) do (
  set "LINE=%%L"
  set "LINE=!LINE:QUICKSERVER=%COMPUTERNAME%!"
  echo !LINE!
) > C:\br2.txt
move /y C:\br2.txt c:\br.txt
```